# NumPy is being defined as np but still getting "NameError: np is not defined"

Tags: python, numpy, nameerror

I have a script here that calls a custom function and runs it in a for loop. The function is suppose to find the roots of a function, defined here as `f(X)`, and use a tolerance value to reject any false roots. The problem is, I keep getting the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-10016a66492e> in <module>
     17 start = tictoc()
     18 for i in range(0,n):
---> 19     fsolvetol(f,x0,q,i,tol)
     20 finish = tictoc() - start
     21 print('Elapsed time is {0} seconds'.format(finish))

~\OneDrive - University of Massachusetts Dartmouth\EAS520\Project1\hw3\customsolver.py in fsolvetol(func, guesses, roots, i, Tol)
      7 def fsolvetol(func,guesses,roots,i,Tol):
      8     import numpy as np
----> 9     roots[i] = fsolve(func,guesses[i])
     10 #     if func(roots[i]) > Tol or func(roots[i]) < -Tol:
     11 #         roots[i] = 1

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Despite having numpy defined as np in both of my scripts. Below are my main script and the custom function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from numpy import pi
from time import perf_counter as tictoc
from customsolver import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Organizing Inputs #
def f(x): return np.sin(3*pi*np.cos(2*pi*x)*np.sin(pi*x))
a = -3; b = 5; n = 4**4
x0 = np.linspace(a,b,n)
q = np.zeros(np.shape(x0))
tol = 10**(-13)
#####################

start = tictoc()
for i in range(0,n):
    fsolvetol(f,x0,q,i,tol)
finish = tictoc() - start
print('Elapsed time is {0} seconds'.format(finish))

# Processing Outputs #
q = np.unique(q) # keep roots with unique values only.
q = q[~np.isnan(q)] # removes the nan value
```

I'm calling the custom function written here as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

# Flags points that fsolve incorrectly assigns as roots within tolerance (now a function!)
def fsolvetol(func,guesses,roots,i,Tol):
    roots[i] = fsolve(func,guesses[i])
    if func(roots[i]) > Tol or func(roots[i]) < -Tol:
        roots[i] = np.nan
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fsolvetol()
```

Despite

Comment: Your code is actually running..I didn't get the error...theouput I got is `Elapsed time is 0.070864499999999 seconds`. Check again if al the imports are right.

Comment: So it turns out when I first received the error, I didn't know that rerunning the line `from customsolver import *` doesn't actually reload the revised functions in the `customsolver.py` script. So it was still working off of the script with where numpy wasn't imported. I don't know why Jupyter Notebook / IPython does this, but if someone would explain this, I would gladly take it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add np. infront of your roots[i], it should be np.roots[i]. Or you  could import roots

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np
from numpy import roots // Just do this and it should be fine

# Flags points that fsolve incorrectly assigns as roots within tolerance (now a function!)
def fsolvetol(func,guesses,roots,i,Tol):
    roots[i] = fsolve(func,guesses[i])
    if func(roots[i]) > Tol or func(roots[i]) < -Tol:
        roots[i] = np.nan
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    fsolvetol()
```

Comment: The `roots` meant in the question are parameters passed to the function not `numpy.roots`, you can clearly see they are accessed with `[]` not `()`.

Comment: I just ran the code and there seems to be nothing wrong with it? is there a problem with your imports?